# Transformar una imagen asp a una imagen vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estoy intentando pasarle la variable `<asp:Image ID="imgEstadoRegistro" runat="server">` al método `CheckUserExists(EstadoImagen As Image, EstadoRegistro As String)` que esta en otra clase y me salta este error.
La imagen del método `CheckUserExists(EstadoImagen As Image, EstadoRegistro As String)` viene de `Imports System.Drawing`

[image: Error que salta]

**Asp clase Login**

`<asp:TextBox ID="tbUsuarioRegistro" runat="server" CssClass="textoLogin" Height="25px" placeholder="Usuario..." Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="checkUserExists"></asp:TextBox>`
`<asp:Image ID="imgEstadoRegistro" runat="server" Height="25px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" Width="25px" />`

**Click handle UsuarioHelper** (problema en la variable "imgEstadoRegistro")

```
Protected Sub checkUserExists(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbUsuarioRegistro.TextChanged
    Dim cadenaConexion As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DSN").ConnectionString)
    UsuarioHelper.CheckUserExists(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DSN").ConnectionString, tbUsuarioRegistro.Text().Trim(), imgEstadoRegistro, lbEstadoRegistro.Text)

End Sub
```

**Metodo para comprobar si existe el usuario**

```
Public Shared Function CheckUserExists(CadenaConexion As String, Usuario As String, Imagen As Image, LabelEstado As String)
    If (Usuario.Length >= 8) Then
        Dim parUsuario As New SqlParameter("@usuario", Usuario)
        Dim consulta As String = "select usuario from Usuarios where usuario = @usuario"
        Dim objDS As DataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consulta, parUsuario)

        If (objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)) Then
            Imagen = Image.FromFile("\css\images_css\ic_cancel_black_24dp_1x.png")
        Else
            Imagen = Image.FromFile("\css\images_css\ic_check_black_24dp_1x.png")
            LabelEstado = ""
        End If
    Else
        LabelEstado = "El usuario tiene que tener 8 caracteres minimo"
        Imagen = Image.FromFile("\css\images_css\ic_cancel_black_24dp_1x.png")
    End If
End Function
```

Gracias por todo, un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, tras dar unas cuantas vueltas por diferentes webs y gracias a algunos miembros de **SOes** he encontrado una "solución"

Directamente he declarado la variable `Imagen` del metodo **CheckUserExists** como `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`, así no hay que convertirla, porque tanto la imagen de mi clase [.aspx](/questions/tagged/.aspx) como la imagen de la clase [.vb](/questions/tagged/.vb) son el mismo formato.

No es la respuesta que buscaba, pero me soluciona las cosas.
Gracias a todos, un saludo